# Using ! or @ in Summernote hint content

Tags: javascript, summernote

In my summernote hint option I have the following

```
hint: {
    match: /\B[@!](\w*)$/,
    search: function (keyword, callback) {
        callback($.grep(mentions, function (i) {
            user = mentionData[i];
            return user.name.indexOf(keyword) === 0;
        }));
    },
    template: function...
    content: function (i) {
        var user = mentionData[i];
        return $('<span>@' + user.username + '</span>')[0];
    }
}
```

I want to be able to insert the @ or ! symbol (whichever one the user initiated the hint with) into the content option. Is there a way to pass the keyword to the content function? or is there a way specific to summernote to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use array hints, example:

```
hint:[
      {
        words: ['apple', 'orange', 'watermelon', 'lemon'],
        match: /\b(\w{1,})$/,
        search: function (keyword, callback) {
        callback($.grep(this.words, function (item) {
         return item.indexOf(keyword) === 0;
        }));
      },
      {
        mentions: ['jayden', 'sam', 'alvin', 'david'],
        match: /\B@(\w*)$/,
        search: function (keyword, callback) {
         callback($.grep(this.mentions, function (item) {
          return item.indexOf(keyword) == 0;
         }));
        },
        content: function (item) {
         return '@' + item;
        }    
      }
    ]
  }
},
```